# Sentences with no verb, but an ablative

Tags: sentence-translation, syntax

Sometimes I will run across sentences that have no verb, but there is an ablative and I am not sure about the right approach to assuming a verb. For example, in this 16th century sentence:

> Erat inter eos & Reginaldinos vetus odium, saepe multis utriusque
>   partis cladibus nobilitatum;

This sentence begins "There was among those and the Reginalds an old hatred, often the nobility of many parts of both ...". Then there is just the word cladibus "in/at the breaking" which I guess could be ablative or dative. Is the reader supposed to assume a missing *erant*. So, it would be "were at the breaking (point)" as though it said "in cladibus erant" or something like that? How do you handle sentences like this?

Comment: Take as one group *saepe multis cladibus* 'often with many  injuries,'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Saepe multis utriusque partis cladibus nobilitatum* can be interpreted as an Ablative Absolute construction whose predicate is the adjectival phrase *saepe multis* and its subject is the nominal phrase *utriusque partis cladibus nobilitatum*. The head of the former is *multis*, whereas the head of the latter is *cladibus*. Lit. 'with the injuries of both parts of their nobilities often being many'. I don't know about the context. So I hope you'll be able to provide a better translation. 
I agree with you that this construction can be given a sentential interpretation (in this reading, the Ablative Absolute construction is possible; no verb is needed) but, this said, notice that it can also be interpreted as merely involving a so-called Ablative of attendant circumstances (i.e., lit. 'often with many injuries of both parts of their nobilities'). In fact, this second interpretation seems quite natural here.

Comment: The “mere” ablative of circumstances feels right to this (inexpert) ear. Simpler too!

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Not only simpler but probably more appropriate too. Cf. also the typical example _senatu frequente_, where two readings are in principle possible: cf. the Ablative absolute, whereby _frequente_ is predicative, and the Ablative of attendant circumstances, whereby this adjective is not predicative but attributive.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that in this English edition of the text (philological.bham.ac.uk/scothist/15lat.html // 22. _Erat inter eos et Reginaldinos vetus odium saepe multis utrisque partis cladibus nobilitatum <acceptis>_) , a participle _acceptis_ is added to highlight the propositional nature of the Ablative constituent. As noted above, this is not necessary provided that the adjective can acquire a predicative nature. Cf. also _Frequenti senatu_  and _Frequenti senatu coacto_ NB: only in the former example _frequenti_ can have a predicative reading.

Comment: I think the presence of *saepe* makes an ablative of circumstance seem odd—perhaps also because I wouldn't expect the latter inside an existential *erat* sentence. On the other hand, *multis...cladibus* makes for an odd ablative absolute, because I somehow don't like the feeling of praedicative *multis* as in "clashes were many". I think I would expect an adjective with a more 'propositional' meaning in an ablative absolute. So I'm inclined to say the sentence is odd either way. Should this be considered proper Latin? In classical Latin, I would perhaps expect a genitive.

Comment: Precisely the combination of the meaning of _saepe_ with _multis_ made me think of the typical syntactically ambiguous example _frequenti senatu/frequentissimo senatu_.  I agree with you that the semantics of _multis_ is not enough to obtain a predicative status but perhaps combined with _saepe_ in this **non-Classical** text such a reading is possible.

Answer (score 4):

The main clause, with a verb is

> Erat  vetus odium,

This ancient hatred is described by an adjective phrase, which tells you the participants,

> inter eos & Reginaldinos

and another longer phrase explaining to some extent how (adverb) it was an *ancient* hatred; i.e. 'often with many clashes'

> saepe multis cladibus

these 'clashes' (within the compound adverb phrase) more precisely described (with an adjective phrase) as being clashes 'of the nobility of each side.'